# How to Configure Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 with PHP and ASP .NET?

Tags: php, dreamweaver, asp.net

I have Wamp Server on my PC and also Visual Studio and I want to Configure Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 with ASP .NET and PHP so that I Can design Dynamic website....

Comment: Can`t, php is compiled on the server side so install Eclipse, Netbeans or Aptana. Use dreamweaver for mock-ups

Comment: @KA_lin that is not true at all. Php/ASP runs in fact on the server side (being wamp in his case). But development can be done in Dreamweaver just like, Eclipse, Netbeans, PhpStorm/IntelliJ or Aptana... Intellisense, code hinting can differ in every IDE but you can write php in notepad if you want.

Comment: I wasn`t expressing myself clearly, It seems he wants to use dreamweaver for the visual part, I was just pointing out that he can`t run php code in the editor to see the full effect :)

Comment: ow, okay then ;) I was thought that was obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if setting up a local testing server in DreamWeaver CS6 is different than CC 2014. Here's out to do it, assuming that CS6 works the same way as CC 2014.

1.) In the Dreamweaver toolbar, choose Site -> New Site...

2.) Choose the "Servers" option on the side of the box that appears, and click on the "+".

[image: Server Setup Dialog]

3.) After you click the "+", you'll see another box appear asking for the server configuration info. The first thing you'll want to change is "Connect using" option. The CC 2014 default is "FTP." Since you are using a WAMP server, you are going to want to change the default to "Local/Network."

[image: Server Setup Dialog #2]

4.) After changing this setting, you'll notice that the requested information also changes. For your server folder, set the root directory for your website. The root directory for your site is going to be in your WAMP server folder. I use IIS instead of WAMP, so that's what I am going to make my directory.

[image: Server Setup Dialog #3]

5.) For the web URL, put `http://localhost`, followed by the root directory of your site. For the website I show here, the root directory is named `MyStackOverflowSite`, so that's what we are going to put after `localhost`.

[image: Server Setup Dialog #4]

6.) Save your server configuration.

7.) Click on the arrow on the "Advanced Settings" tab, and choose "Local Info." In the options that appear, change "Links relative to" from "Document" to "Site Root."

8.) Save, and from now on whenever you are working on your site, Dreamweaver will be able to use WAMP to handle PHP as long as WAMP is running.